# How to handle keys of JsonField in Django?

Tags: python, json, django

I have a model with a JsonField called "settings".
If I want to add a new "field" (key) or get the value of the "field" I have to write the following:

```
# save
instance.settings['color'] = 'red'
instance.save()

# get value
instance.settings['color']
```

I don't like this because of the "hard-coded" color string.
Is there a good approach to handle the keys of a JsonField?
Should I use something like this or is there a better solution:

```
# settings (settings.py file)
COLOR = 'color'

# save
instance.settings[COLOR] = 'red'
instance.save()

# get value
instance.settings[COLOR]
```

Comment: I would place `COLOR` in the model class. Also maybe create a property for the json field. This actually depends on the task, how often do you need to access the field and do you need to validate it in some way

Comment: The property is a great idea, I didn't think about that. Thanks